# How to use the constant resolution during webrtc video transmission?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, sdp

I am using [janus](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) to build my webrtc SFU server. I need the chrome browser to send the video resolution from a start to a fixed value and remain unchanged during the transfer. Where should I set it?

I tried setting the [degradationPreference](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-rtcrtpsendparameters-degradationpreference) in the js code, but it didn't work, the resolution will still change, it seems that chrome does [not support this parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSendParameters#Browser_compatibility).

```
var senderList = config.pc.getSenders();
var sender = config.pc.getSenders().find(function(s) {return s.track.kind == "video"});
if(sender) {
    var parameters = sender.getParameters();
    parameters.degradationPreference = "maintain-resolution";
    sender.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

[Image1 with varying resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph7LP.png)

[Image2 with varying resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oplLh.png)

I looked at frameHeightSend/frameWidthSend in `chrome://webrtc-internals`, hoping it will keep the same value from the start, but now it grows slowly at startup and will fluctuate during subsequent transfers.

**I found a [message](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029411972-How-do-I-keep-my-resolution-constant-in-a-screen-sharing-app-) that sets the constant resolution in IOS, which is set when the screen is shared, and whether there are similar settings in chrome.**

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?